# Dataset of students' responses to programming task in text

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, dataset

I'm working on an Intelligent Tutoring System for programming where the tutor asks questions about code and the student answer in natural language (English). As a part of analyzing the answer, I'm using text similarity. However, this does not tell me what wrong with the answer i.e., misunderstand a concept. Therefore, I'm Thinking of using ML to classify the responses and identify any misconceptions.

My question is, where can I find a dataset that contains textual answers for programming tasks (JAVA)?

Answer (score 1):

You can find tons of JAVA questions/answers in a `Stack Overflow dataset`.

Here is the links for downloading data and querying with BigQuery API  https://www.kaggle.com/stackoverflow/stackoverflow

Filter on tag `JAVA` and you are good to analyse, explore your data and do some NLP on it.